# How to delete all folders in a directory using bash?

Tags: bash, directory, rm

Basically, I want to delete all subfolders, but leave all the files intact. For example:

```
Folder1/
    randomStuff/
         nope.txt
    installer.jar
    build.sh
```

I want randomStuff and its files deleted, but keep installer.jar and build.sh intact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the fact that a filename that ends in a slash always refers to a directory, and never a regular file.

The command

```
rm -r -- ./*/
```

will accomplish what you describe.

Comment: `rm -r ./*/`, `rm -r -- */`, or `rm -r -- ./*/` please.

Comment: @saga, huh? The original was `rm -r */`, which, in an empty directory expands to `rm -r */`, which will give an error from `rm` since the file/directory `*` doesn't exist. If there was a directory named `-f`, it would be added to the command line as `-f/`, which would probably give an error about an invalid option `/`. Even with `nullglob` set, the whole word would disappear, not just the asterisk, so `rm` would still complain about a missing target. I can't see how that could target the user's home directory?

Comment: Sure, in general it's a good idea to protect against file names being taken as options to the command, but I think the most dangerous one for `rm` is `-r`, which was already given here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find Folder1/* -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```

This will search for folders within that directory and run the `rm -rf` command on each found.

Comment: Why '+'? It will make the command unnecessarily slow. Adding `-depth 1` wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score -1):

I used awk command to achieve the same.

---

```
ls -ltr | awk '$1 ~ "^dr"{print "rm -rvf" " " $9}’ | sh
```

---

Comment: I down voted, because [parsing the `ls` output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls), plus because of using text processing tools after that too.